# Browser screenshot as bitmap in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, webpage-screenshot

I'm trying to get the screenshot of a given URL as a bitmap image on the Windows Phone. The WebBrowser class does not seem to have the DrawToBitmap method.

Any pointers on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take a screenshot of the `WebBrowser Control` as there seems to be a bug with the way it works with WriteableBitmaps. An alternative method could be to send the URL to a web service which takes a screenshot on the server and returns it back to your app.

Answer (score 3):

Use `WriteableBitmap` to render the `WebBrowser` control and its contents to a bitmap as described by Laurent's article [Taking a screenshot from within a Silverlight #WP7 application](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2010/12/28/taking-a-screenshot-from-within-a-silverlight-wp7-application.aspx), which also explains how to save it to the media library.

Comment: The article mentions that it doesnt work on the contents of a WebBrowser Control. That is exactly what I wanted to do...